# Add a "0" at the beginning of the values if the length of the value is less than "2" using FME

Tags: fme-transformer

I have an Excel reader with an attribute in string format that contains the speed of bikes. I want to add a "0" at the beginning of the values if the length of the value is less than "2". It is quite simple and easily doable in Python, SQL or even Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Use StringPadder transformer or a AttributeManager with the value

```
@PadLeft(@value(myfield),2,‘0’)
```